# Why is T continuous?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, dynamical-systems

Let $T\colon X\to X$, with $X=\left\{0,1,2\right\}^{\mathbb{Z}}$, desribe the following dynamics:

- 1 becomes 2
- 2 becomes 0
- 0 becomes 1 if at least one of its two neighbours is 1, otherwise it remains 0

Equip $\left\{0,1,2\right\}$ with the discrete topology and $X$ with the associated product topology (with is compact by Tychonov).

Maybe a silly question, but: Why is $T$ continuous?

Is there a very simple reason I do not see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that a map into a product space is continuous iff all its components are. Hence to check where $T \colon X \to X$ is continuous it suffices to look at all $T_n = \pi_n \circ T \colon X \to \{0,1,2\}$, where $\pi_n \colon X \to \{0,1,2\}$ denotes the $n$-th projection, $n \in \mathbf Z$.

Now, 
$$ T_n^{-1}[\{2\}] = \pi_n^{-1}[\{1\}]
$$
which is open, as $\{1\}$ is open and $\pi_n$ is continuous, moreover
$$ T_n^{-1}[\{1\}] = \pi_n^{-1}[\{0\}] \cap \bigl(\pi_{n-1}^{-1}[\{1\}] \cup \pi_{n+1}^{-1}[\{1\}] \bigr) $$
is open and 
$$ T_n^{-1}[\{0\}] = \pi_n^{-1}[\{2\}] \cup \pi_n^{-1}[\{0\}] \cap \bigl(\pi_{n-1}^{-1}[\{0,2\}] \cap \pi_{n+1}^{-1}[\{0,2\}] \bigr) $$
also is. Hence, $T_n$ is continuous, as $n$ was arbitrary, $T$ is.

Comment: Also, all functions from a set equipped with discrete topology to any topological space are continuous.